# Navigation on 404 page

Tags: navigation, 404, dynamic

I have dynamic navigation based on the current page in my header snippet. I have it setup like this:

```
    {if segment_1 == "" OR "{404}" == "true"}
        {exp:structure:nav start_from="/wat-doen-wij" max_depth="1" current_class="active"}
    {/if}

    {if segment_1 == "wat-doen-wij" AND "{404}" != "true"}
        <div class="subnav_wrapper">
            {exp:structure:nav start_from="/wat-doen-wij" max_depth="1" current_class="active"}
        </div>
    {/if}

    {if segment_1 != "" AND segment_1 != "wat-doen-wij" AND segment_1 != "zoekresultaten" AND segment_1 != "waarbij-helpen-wij" AND "{404}" != "true"}
        <div class="subnav_wrapper">
            {exp:structure:nav start_from="{freebie_1}" max_depth="1" current_class="active"}
        </div>
    {/if}
```

On my 404 template I use the following statement to set my 404 variable:

```
{preload_replace:404="true"}
```

However, this breaks all my other pages. How can I fix this? 
I need to know which template I am currently on. Can I do it based on header infomation? 
I can't use {segment} because segment_1 could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

`{preload_replace:404="true"}` will never work as you are using it because it's not passed to the header. This variable is only available for use in the same template... [**docs for Preload Text Replacements are here**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/preload_replacement.html).

> Preload Replacements act as a straight string replacement ***for use
>   later in the same template.***

Instead use this in your 404 and header templates:

**IN 404 TEMPLATE:**

```
{embed="includes/header" 404="true"}
```

**IN HEADER TEMPLATE:**

```
{if segment_1 == "" OR "{embed:404}" == "true"}
    {exp:structure:nav start_from="/wat-doen-wij" max_depth="1" current_class="active"}
{/if}

{if segment_1 == "wat-doen-wij" AND "{embed:404}" != "true"}
    <div class="subnav_wrapper">
        {exp:structure:nav start_from="/wat-doen-wij" max_depth="1" current_class="active"}
    </div>
{/if}

{if segment_1 != "" AND segment_1 != "wat-doen-wij" AND segment_1 != "zoekresultaten" AND segment_1 != "waarbij-helpen-wij" AND "{embed:404}" != "true"}
    <div class="subnav_wrapper">
        {exp:structure:nav start_from="{freebie_1}" max_depth="1" current_class="active"}
    </div>
{/if}
```

Comment: I have found a solution in the meantime, but thank you for your response. I will use this in the future.

However, I use snippets for my header and footer. Would this also work for snippets instead of embedded templates?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your question for others with this issue to find. I don't use Snippets for header/footer so can't answer that part of your question. Best test is to try it. Feel

Answer (score 0):

Not really solving your problems here but I think you need to be aware that you've got 3 nav tags inside advanced conditionals, just for your 404 'problem'.

Doing it this way, all the nav tags are going to get parsed, always. This is adding a bunch of overhead (queries, template parsing etc) to every single page load on your site.

There are lots of articles about this if you google 'ExpressionEnging parse order' but [here's one to get you started](http://www.derekallard.com/blog/post/simple-vs-complex-conditionals-in-expressionengine-templates).

IMO a 404 doesn't need a subnav, it just needs to obviously tell the user they are on a broken page. Main navigation, yes. Sub navigation of any section they *might* be on, not really.

Comment: I am aware of the parse order, but I will look into it, thanks for mentioning it.

The page does require a subnav, mainly because of the way the homepage is setup. Sadly I can't just exclude it on the 404 page, because if I could do that I could also include it..